# Discord.py - InvalidArgument: This webhook does not have a token associated with it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot and wanted to add an impersonate command. The bot creates a webhook to achieve it but it can't delete webhooks.

I get this error:
"Error: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: This webhook does not have a token associated with it"

I looked online but saw no one else with the same issue.

Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def clone(ctx, member:Discord.User=None, *, message:str=None):
    if member == None or message == None:
        await ctx.send("You need to give a member (mention) and message.")
        return

    webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
    await webhook.send(
        message, username=member.name + " (fake)", avatar_url=member.avatar_url)

    webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
    for webhook in webhooks:
        await webhook.delete()
```

Comment: Why are you looking up the webhooks in the channel if you just made the webhook? Cant you use your webhook variable instead of getting all the webhooks with ctx.channel.webhooks() and deleting every single one of them? Not to mention other bots and users can make webhooks too, you want to delete theirs too?

Comment: good point, i set it up to just delete the webhook it made and it works now. Thanks